# Is the Nintendo Switch backwards compatible?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, nintendo-switch

Is the Nintendo Switch [backwards compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) with games or accessories from previous Nintendo consoles?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Region locking is something that's no so obvious. while Nintendo has been adding Region Locking in the past this wasn't the case with at-least the GBA and the NDS up to the NDSi. from the NDSi -> WiiU they had added Region Locking and with the PS3 and PS4 Region Locking for games is supported but it's up to the developers to use it or not so it's not enfroced (PS3 games aren't region locked but Persona 4 Arena was). Backwards Comparability is obvious when (if i recall correctly) the Nintendo Switch has no Disk Drive and cartridges are a totally different shape to DS ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Nintendo Switch is [not backwards compatible](http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/02/07/nintendo-explains-lack-of-switch-backwards-compatibility) with any previous Nintendo consoles or controllers. Nintendo has mentioned they are considering re-releasing more Wii U titles on the Switch, such as the upcoming [Mario Kart 8 Deluxe](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/mario-kart-8-deluxe-switch).

Comment: Despite no backwards compatibility, likely due to cartridge vs. disc, I thought the Switch was going to have an emulator at some point?

Comment: The Virtual Console will be returning eventually, but if the Virtual Console's precedent stands, previously purchased VC games will not carry over to the switch, and there's till no way to play previously purchased physical media, both of which are the key concepts of backwards-compatibility.

Comment: They recently announced support for Gamecube controllers for Super Smash Bros. Ultimate.  Presumably, this will be similar to how the WiiU did it via a dongle.

Answer (score 2):

No. Although the Nintendo Switch is not backwards compatible, Nintendo has been releasing older games from the NES and SNES, with their new platform: Switch Online. Additionally, Nintendo has been releasing some older titles from the Wii and Wii U, which have been remastered to be compatible with the system.

Answer (score 0):

While there are some Wii U games ported to the Switch, you have to buy and beat them again, and no hardware is compatible with both consoles, although SSB Ultimate will see the re-rerelease of the GameCube controller, along with the adapter.